# show first value from rowsource

Tags: excel, vba

show first value directly on combobox depends on selected item before

```
If plancombo.Value = "4 Years" Then ComboBox1.RowSource = "D5Fouryears"
```

i want to find the first value on combobox not to go select it (combobox1)and if i need to change open combobox and select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a combobox show the first value, set its ListIndex to 0:

```
Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
```